# Weka remove attribute temporarily and later restore

Tags: java, classification, weka

In Weka (using Java), I would like to successsively fit classifiers to different subsets of attributes of the same dataset.

Is there a way to build the Instances object only once, and then remove the non-selected features but only temporarily, so they can be efficiently restored and used later in case the attribute is needed later to build another classifier, without having to create every time a totally new Instances object from scratch?

I am aware of method [deleteAttributeAt](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.stable/weka/core/Instances.html#deleteAttributeAt-int-)() which says that

> A deep copy of the attribute information is performed before the
>   attribute is deleted

and also of class [Remove](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.dev/weka/filters/unsupervised/attribute/Remove.html#setAttributeIndicesArray-int:A-) but I'm not sure this is what I need.

Comment: `weka.filters.unsupervised.attribute.Remove` is a filter that removes your specified set of attributes from the dataset - can you use that in conjunction with `weka.classifiers.meta.FilteredClassifier` ?

Answer (score 0):

Create new Instances objects at each stage and use the appropriately.

For example, below example is using instances object without class and normalized to build a cluster.

Use rawData to get original instances. Hope this helps.

```
    final SimpleKMeans kmeans = new SimpleKMeans();

    final String[] options = weka.core.Utils
            .splitOptions("-init 0 -max-candidates 100 -periodic-pruning 10000 -min-density 2.0 -t1 -1.25 -t2 -1.0 -N 10 -A \"weka.core.EuclideanDistance -R first-last\" -I 500 -num-slots 1 -S 50");
    kmeans.setOptions(options);

    kmeans.setSeed(1000);
    kmeans.setPreserveInstancesOrder(true);
    kmeans.setNumClusters(5);
    kmeans.setMaxIterations(1000);

    final BufferedReader datafile = readDataFile("/Users/data.arff");
    final Instances rawData = new Instances(datafile);
    rawData.setClassIndex(classIndex);

    //remove class column[0] from cluster
    final Remove removeFilter = new Remove();
    removeFilter.setAttributeIndices("" + (rawData.classIndex() + 1));
    removeFilter.setInputFormat(rawData);
    final Instances dataNoClass = Filter.useFilter(rawData, removeFilter);

    //normalize
    final Normalize normalizeFilter = new Normalize();
    normalizeFilter.setIgnoreClass(true);
    normalizeFilter.setInputFormat(dataNoClass);
    final Instances data = Filter.useFilter(dataNoClass, normalizeFilter);

    kmeans.buildClusterer(data);
```